# How to add line break in textContent (JS)?

Tags: javascript

This is a snippet of code, I want to add a line break after each statement. Tried using "/r/n" and "<-br>" none of them seem to work fine.

```
**else {
    para.textContent = num + ' squared is ' + squared(num) + '. ' +
    num + ' cubed is ' + cubed(num) + '. ' +
    num + ' factorial is ' + factorial(num) + '.';
      }**
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `textContent` you can use `innerHTML` and `<br />`s.

```
para.innerHTML = num + ' squared is ' + squared(num) + '.<br />' +
    num + ' cubed is ' + cubed(num) + '.<br />' +
    num + ' factorial is ' + factorial(num) + '.';
```

---

You can also solve this using CSS. Just add this style `white-space: pre;` to the target element: 
    para.setAttribute('style', 'white-space: pre;');

Comment: there are also various things you can do in CSS to get line breaks recognised like the `pre` tag does

Comment: This won't work cause you can't insert elements (ie br) to textContent

Comment: @A.Meshu good catch! I edited my answer now. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using .textcontent or .innerHTML, you can use .innerText. The <br> elements would be seen as line breaks.